Laplace Transform solve ODE second order
Find ODE second order using Laplace Transform
$y" + 3y' + 4y = 3t $
$; y(0) = 2$
$; y'(0) = 2$
( This is imaginary roots)
I have found the answer using undetermined coefficient but i got stuck when solve the question using Laplace and the result is not same it should be same. I don't know which the step I skipped and curious if you guys can find my mistakes
The answer is for general solution : $y(x) = e^\frac{-3x}{2}(Acos\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}x+Bsin\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}x )+\frac{3}{4}x-\frac{9}{16}$
The answer when intial value plug in : $y(x) = e^\frac{-3x}{2}(\frac{41}{16}cos\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}x+ {\frac{-118}{32{\sqrt{7}}}sin\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}x)} +\frac{3}{4}x-\frac{9}{16}$
However, I will help you to make the answer is not too long
there is $Fs_1$ and $Fs_2$
$Fs_1 = {3 \over (s^2)(s+\frac{3}{2}-\frac{i\sqrt{7}}{2})(s+\frac{3}{2}+\frac{i\sqrt{7}}{2})} = \frac{A}{s}+ \frac{B}{s^2}+  {C \over (s+\frac{3}{2}-\frac{i\sqrt{7}}{2})} + {D \over (s+\frac{3}{2}+\frac{i\sqrt{7}}{2})} $
$Fs_2 = {2s+7 \over (s+\frac{3}{2}-\frac{i\sqrt{7}}{2})(s+\frac{3}{2}+\frac{i\sqrt{7}}{2})} = {C \over (s+\frac{3}{2}-\frac{i\sqrt{7}}{2})} + {D \over (s+\frac{3}{2}+\frac{i\sqrt{7}}{2})} $
That's it only I can help.

This is what I get. I used the computer to help with the inverse Laplace transform as they are hard for me to do by hand now.

@Nasser Thanks . But Can I know what the computer you used to solve this ?

I solved it myself, but used Maple to help find the Laplace transformation.

@Nasser hey , bro . can you explain why the result not same as my result which solved by undetermined coeffiecient

it should be same

I get exactly the same using undetermined coeff. See this  you must have made mistake in your guess for particular solution?

@Nasser okay bro , thank you so much . you really fast to answer this question .you're smart one

Hint:
By taking Laplace Transform two both sides of given equation we get
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}\left\{y''\right\}+3\mathcal{L}\left\{y'\right\}+4\mathcal{L}\left\{y\right\}&=\dfrac3{s^2}\\
s^2\mathcal{L}\left\{y\right\}-sy(0)-y'(0)+3\left[s\mathcal{L}\left\{y\right\}-y(0)\right]+4\mathcal{L}\left\{y\right\}&=\dfrac3{s^2}\\
\end{align*}
By putting $Y(s)=\mathcal{L}\left\{y\right\}$ and taking initial conditions we have
\begin{align*}
s^2Y(s)-2s-2+3\left[sY(s)-2\right]+4Y(s)&=\dfrac3{s^2}\\
\left(s^2+3s+4\right)Y(s)-2s-8&=\dfrac3{s^2}\\
\left(s^2+3s+4\right)Y(s)&=\dfrac3{s^2}+2s+8\\
Y(s)&=\dfrac{3}{s^2(s^2+3s+4)}+\dfrac{2s+8}{s^2+3s+4}...(1)
\end{align*}

The first fraction can be written as
\begin{align*}
\dfrac3{s^2(s^2+3s+4)}&=\dfrac As+\dfrac B{s^2}+\dfrac{Cs+D}{s^2+3s+4}...(*)
\end{align*}
where $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ are real numbers. In order to determine them multiply both sides of (*) by $s^2(s^2+3s+4)$:
\begin{align*}
3&=As(s^2+3s+4)+B(s^2+3s+4)+(Cs+D)s^2\\
3&=(A+C)s^3+(3A+B+D)s^2+(4A+3B)s+4B
\end{align*}
then
\begin{eqnarray}
A&&&+&C&&&=0\\
3A&+&B&&&+&D&=0\\
4A&+&3B&&&&&=0 \\
&&4B&&&&&=3
\end{eqnarray}
by solving this system of linear equations we get $A=-\tfrac9{16},B=\tfrac34,C=\tfrac9{16}$ and $D=\tfrac{15}{16}$, then
$$\dfrac3{s^2(s^2+3s+4)}=\frac{-\tfrac9{16}}s+\frac{\tfrac 34}{s^2}+\frac{\tfrac9{16}s+\tfrac{15}{16}}{s^2+3s+4}$$
So
\begin{align*}
Y(s)&=\frac{-\tfrac9{16}}s+\frac{\tfrac 34}{s^2}+\frac{\tfrac9{16}s+\tfrac{15}{16}}{s^2+3s+4}+\dfrac{2s+8}{s^2+3s+4}\\
&=\frac{-\tfrac9{16}}s+\frac{\tfrac 34}{s^2}+\frac{\tfrac{41}{16}s+\tfrac{143}{16}}{s^2+3s+4}\\
&=\frac{-\tfrac9{16}}s+\frac{\tfrac 34}{s^2}+\frac{\tfrac{41}{16}\left(s+\tfrac32\right)+\tfrac{163}{32}}{\left(s+\tfrac32\right)^2+\tfrac74}
\end{align*}
By taking inverse Laplace transform to both sides the solution is found:
$$y=-\tfrac9{16}+\tfrac34t+\tfrac{41}{16}e^{-3t/2}\cos\left(\tfrac{\sqrt 7}2t\right)+\tfrac{163}{16\sqrt{7}}e^{-3t/2}\sin\left(\tfrac{\sqrt 7}2t\right)$$

I have tried the hint but it's same , I got stuck
